# Action after user saves Appointment

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to display a simple message (i.e. "OK") AFTER the user saves an Appointment using Outlook 2016. I was thinking about enhancing an existing  (VB.NET) VSTO Outlook add-in that would hook on the AppointmentItem AfterWrite event on the add-in startup; 
what i've come up with so far is:

```
Private WithEvents Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Inspectors = Me.Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private WithEvents apptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles Inspectors.NewInspector
    Dim apptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.AppointmentItem)
    If Not (apptItem Is Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show("OK")
        apptItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub
```

This is actually displaying the message ("OK") when i open the appointment window, what i want is to display it only after the appointment has been created/saved/written (user basically clicks on Save&Close). Do you have an idea how would this be done ?

LATER EDIT:
I managed by using this code:

```
Private WithEvents Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        Inspectors = Me.Application.Inspectors
        AddHandler Inspectors.NewInspector, AddressOf Me.objinspectors_NewInspector
    End Sub

    Public WithEvents apptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector)
        Dim apptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        If Not (apptItem Is Nothing) Then
            If apptItem.MeetingStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olNonMeeting Then
                'only for the AppointmentItem Object, we hook on the AfterWrite event to process what we want after the Appointment has been saved.
                AddHandler apptItem.AfterWrite, AddressOf AppointmentSaved
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub AppointmentSaved() Handles apptItem.AfterWrite
        MessageBox.Show("Appointment saved")
    End Sub
```

to display a message when the Appointment is saved. Next step would be to get access to the Appointment object properties when displaying the message; any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an event handler on the apptItem variable. Declare the apptItem_AfterWrite event handler.
Also keep in mind that, since you can have more than one open item, you really need to have a list of items, not a single AppointmeentItem type variable.